# Dependency Injection while dynamic assembly loading

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, dependency-injection

i have a winforms applicatoin that has a lot of implementations of IOrderDataLoader.  Other teams are starting to build their own new implementations of IOrderDataLoader.  So we switched our app to look in a directories of Dlls and load all classes that implement IOrderDataLoader using reflection.  This way other groups can deploy their dlls on their own and the main app loads them on demand.

The problem is one of the implementations that we have as an internal project that we are trying to move out into its own deployment has a number of dependencies.  How i do i break this out and load it up with all the dependencies?  All the other data loader have empty constructors so i simply just loop . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF). It is a framework for doing what you've already done, and supports dependency injection in the style you request.

Comment: Except MEF doesn't work with EntLib. They really should have designed MEF to only "discover" and delegate the "build" back to using unity.

Comment: @Sleeper Smith: Have a look at the MEF/Unity integration in the MEF Contrib project: http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Integration